# Как добавить строку по нажатию на кнопку в html

Tags: javascript, html, css

есть страница с окном входа, нужно по нажатию на кнопку регистрация, появлялось еще одно поле, например (1 номер, 2 пароль, 3 повторить пароль). Да и как сделать так чтобы кнопки еще поменяли название свое, у меня изначально кнопка sign in, после нажатия кнопки register нужно поменять название на "register", а сверху поменять текст у "sign in " и "register"
На первой фотке так как сейчас, а на второй так как надо сделать, надеюсь там все понятно что нужно.

(ссылка на index.html и css файл) --> https://yadi.sk/d/lNa9LS7Aa0YFxA

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Для начала добавьте все элементы которые нужны для регистрации. Затем, тем элементам, которые нужно скрыть на странице входа, добавьте класс, например, "class". Далее создайте еще класс, например, "hide". В hide пропишите `display: none`. В js (jquerry) нужно прописать такую логику:

```
if ([нажатие на кнопку осуществляется]) {
      $(".class").addClass("hide");
    } else {
      $(".class").removeClass("hide");
    }
```

2 вариант. Просто создать еще один отдельный html для регистрации и при нажатии на кнопку переходить на него.

P.S. Подретактируйте мой ответ, пожалуйста.